# Select outer layer of hollow object

Tags: modeling, mesh, selection-tools, faces

I currently have a hollow sphere, and I want to select the faces on the outside layer of the sphere, but when I do <kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> to select faces, it only selects the faces on the interior layer. Here's an example:

[image]

And here's a zoomed in version:

[image]

How can I select the faces on the outside layer?

Comment: By definition a hollow object shouldn't really have more than one layer, so the term 'outside layer' might be mis-appropriated. Do you mean you want to select only one side of each face, namely the side that faces outwards? This is not possible, you can only select a face, not a side of the face (like there are two sides to a coin)

Comment: by chance is that a Mesh with a Solidify modifier added (but unapplied) and are you expecting to be able to select the geometry generated by the Modifier ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a Solidify modifier, you can't select the 'virtual' geometry generated by the modifier *separately* until it is applied.

[image]

The faces coloured in orange here are the real geometry, and the grey faces are 'virtual' geometry, this can't be selected separately. If you want to do something with the outer or inner layer you will need to Apply the modifier, that makes all geometry of that object 'real'.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've done something extraordinary, like selecting all of the faces and extruding them away from the center of the sphere, or added a modifier, a hollow sphere has only one layer of faces. I don't see anything in your close up image, though to suggest you've done this so <kbd>B</kbd> followed by <kbd>LMB</kbd> selects that one layer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking.
My best guess is you wish to select, or prevent selecting, that which is behind direct visibility.
If this is the case, toggling the following function will solve the issue.

[image: Blender Interface]

If this doesn't solve your problem. Please try to better explain your situation.